# How can I extend an abstract EventEmitter class, with some default events?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, eventemitter

Could anyone help with this please?

How can I extend an abstract `EventEmitter` class, with common events? (I'm using https://github.com/andywer/typed-emitter)

**Example:**

```js
import EventEmitter from "events";
import TypedEmitter from "typed-emitter";

type BaseEvents = {
  BASE_EVENT: (arg: string) => void;
};

abstract class BaseEmitter<T> extends (EventEmitter as {
  new <T>(): TypedEmitter<T>;
})<T> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // How can I make this type safe ????
    this.emit("BASE_EVENT", "string-value"); // <-- How can I achieve type safety here
  }
}

type ImpOneEvents = {
  C1_EVENT: (a: number) => void;
};
class ImpOne extends BaseEmitter<ImpOneEvents> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.emit("C1_EVENT", 1); // OK: type checks ok (GOOD)
    this.emit("C1_EVENT", "bla"); // ERROR: string not assignable (GOOD)
  }
}

type ImpTwoEvents = {
  C2_EVENT: (a: boolean) => void;
};
class ImpTwo extends BaseEmitter<ImpTwoEvents> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.emit("C2_EVENT", true); // OK: type checks ok (GOOD)
  }
}

const impTwo = new ImpTwo();
impTwo.on("C2_EVENT", (a) => {
  parseFloat(a); // ERROR: Type of boolean not assignable to parameter of type string (GOOD)
});
```

I've tried

```
type BaseEvents = {
  BASE_EVENT: (arg: string) => void;
};

abstract class BaseEmitter<T = {}> extends (EventEmitter as {
  new <T>(): TypedEmitter<T>;
})<T & BaseEvents> {
...
```

And lots of other things. The above results in

`Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Arguments<(T & BaseEvents)["BASE_EVENT"]>'.`

For line

```
this.emit("BASE_EVENT", "string-value"); // <-- How can I achieve type safety here
```

Comment: Type of `C2_EVENT: (a: boolean) => void;`. `a` is of type `boolean` here, and `parseFloat` is `declare function parseFloat(string: string): number;`. So, a type mismatch is occurring.

Comment: Change type to `C2_EVENT: (a: string | boolean) => void;` in case you want to handle both `boolean` and `string` types.

Comment: @NalinRanjan yes, this error is left in to demonstrate what type safety *is* occuring. I am missing type safety for `BASE_EVENT` and would like to know how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains how to do this, added in https://github.com/andywer/typed-emitter/pull/8

Apparently the TypeScript syntax to extend a class with type checking on events would be like this -

```ts
class MyEventEmitter extends (EventEmitter as new () => TypedEmitter<MyEvents>) {
  // ...
}
```